# MySql: SELECT ... FOR UPDATE break before doing the UPDATE

Tags: mysql, transactions

I'm doing a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE to lock one record, then doing some calculations and then doing the actual UPDATE. I'm working on an InnoDB-database.

But the calculations might end up in a state where I do not want to execute the UPDATE. How do I cancel the lock in this situation?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InnoDB is made for this. You need to [manage your transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html).

- Before doing your `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, do `START TRANSACTION`.
- Then do your `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.
- Then do the rest of your database work.
- Then do `COMMIT`.

If you decide you don't want to complete your update work, do `ROLLBACK` instead of `COMMIT`, and every change within your transaction is discarded. The database returns to the state right before `START TRANSACTION`.

Don't forget the `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` especially when debugging. If you do forget, your database may appear to lock up, because a future `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` operation may wait for your `COMMIT`. (Don't ask how I know this.  :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.